# Why does plugin_url append absolute file path?

Tags: plugins, customization

I'm, passing the plugin url parameter to my .js file using:

```
wp_enqueue_script('nova-payflow-plugin');
wp_localize_script('my-payflow-plugin', 'pluginValues', array(
    'pluginUrl' => plugins_url(__DIR__),
));
```

In my script, I retrieve what should be a url to my plugin folder, but it looks like this:

```
http://mysubdomain.mydomain.local/wp-content/plugins/C:/xampp/htdocs/mywebfolder/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin
```

On the Linux production server it does a similar thing:

```
https://mysubdomain.mydomain.online/wp-content/plugins/homepages/40/d107997204/htdocs/mywebfolder/wp-content/plugins/my-payflow
```

Note that in the plugins url, a fully qualified Windows path appears appended immediately after wp-content/plugins/

Why does plugins_url add the absolute file path, but more importantly, I don't want it appended to the url string.

Here is how I'm enqueuing the scripts, if it matters to the question:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'npf_styles_and_scripts');
function npf_styles_and_scripts() {
    wp_register_style('nova-payflow-plugin', plugins_url('css/npf.css',__FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style('nova-payflow-plugin');
    wp_register_script( 'nova-payflow-plugin', plugins_url('js/npf.js',__FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script('nova-payflow-plugin');
    wp_localize_script('nova-payflow-plugin', 'pluginValues', array(
    'pluginUrl' => plugins_url(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: you don't use the function conveniently, read the documentation : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Comment: Can you share with us how you are registering the `my-payflow-plugin` script? I can only see the enquing

Comment: @TomJNowell, sure. Please see the last section I added to the question.

Comment: thanks, how are you testing the value of `pluginUrl`? I hope you're not making AJAX calls to a PHP file in that folder, major security issues if you are, amongst other reasons, there are far, far better ways to do AJAX in WP that are safer faster and easier.

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm outputting the value of pluginUrl in an alert. Yes, I am making AJAX calls to a PHP file in my plugin folder.

Comment:  that's extreme bad practice, is there a reason you aren't making your AJAX calls to a REST endpoint using the built in WP functions? You could sidestep all of this and make everything simpler/easier/faster

Comment: @TomJNowell I accept your admonition against using direct AJAX, and I will make myself learn the "WordPress way". With that said, however, my question really isn't about an AJAX call. I want the path to myplugin/assets/img/dollar.png as the src for images, icons, etc. in an img tag. For some reason the `plugins_url(__DIR__)` returns a file path as the last part of the url path, and because the website is on a local (Windows) installation, and a remote (Linux) installation, I don't want to have to figure out special parsing schemes to extract just the relative url path.

Comment: I take it these are images etc that are referenced via relative URLs in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly. it doesn't look like you're using the `$src` for your `wp_enqueue_script`
Then from the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) I found the following similar code:

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js');
wp_localize_script('my-script', 'myScript', array(
    'pluginsUrl' => plugins_url(),
));
```

Perhaps try the following:

```
wp_enqueue_script('nova-payflow-plugin', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js');
wp_localize_script('nova-payflow-plugin', 'pluginValues', array(
    'pluginUrl' => plugins_url(),
));
```

But change the $src value above which is:

> /js/my-script.js

Comment: You don't have to specify anything other than the first parameter when enquing if you've already registered it. Those additional parameters are there so you can register and enqueue at the same time, e.g. to enqueue jQuery you do `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );`

Comment: I don't know if I misstated the problem. The problem is not enqueuing the script. My script works. My problem is that plugins_url returns a "url", and appended to the url is a file path: `http://mysubdomain.mydomain.local/wp-content/plugins/C:/xampp/htdocs/mywebfolder/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin`